# The method add (int, R.String) in the type ArrayList<R.String> is not applicable for the arguments(int, String)

Tags: java, android, addition

i've look on google and on the stack overflow and have not been able to find an answer that wants to work. I'm following a tutorial from the book "Professional android 4 application development" that creates a To do list. the only error in my code is what eclipse is giving me as an error message in my code, once i can fix this i believe it should run fine but i have been staring at it for an hour now and the frustration has got to me i can't understand what is wrong with the code and why i'm getting the error message in my code.

it only underlines the one word add which i have presented in the code below with three * on each side of the word any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Inflate the view to the main screen
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do_list);

    // Get the references to the UI widgets
    ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    final EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);

    // create the array list of to do items
    final ArrayList<string> todoItems = new ArrayList<string>();

    // Create the array list of to do items
    final ArrayAdapter<string> aa;

    // Create the Array Adapter to bind the array to the list view
    aa = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems);

    // Bind the array adapter to the List View
    myListView.setAdapter(aa);

    myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)
                        || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    todoItems.***add***(0, myEditText.getText().toString());
                    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    myEditText.setText(" ");
                    return true;
                }
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Looking at the structure, it seems if you remove the "0" argument in the add function, it should work...

Comment: Thanks for the input but unfortunately it did not work :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace

```
ArrayList<string>
```

by

```
ArrayList<String>
```

Comment: Dystroy thankyou aha, such a silly mistake by me (Note to self check spelling next time)

Comment: Jesus why don't they come with a better editor to point this out ... i'm missing visual studio :(